# How to delete characters in a string according to a second string?

Tags: r

Consider these two strings:

```
string1 <- "GCTCCC...CTCCATGAAGTA...CTTCACATCCGTGT.CCGGCCTGGCCGCGGAGAGCCC"
string_reference <- "GCTCCC...CTCCATGAAGTATTTCTTCACATCCGTGT.CCGGCCTGGCCGCGGAGAGCCC"
```

How do I easily remove the dots in "string1", but only those dots that are in the same position in "string_reference"?

Expected output:

```
string1 = "GCTCCCCTCCATGAAGTA...CTTCACATCCGTGTCCGGCCTGGCCGCGGAGAGCCC"
```

Comment: simple loop stepping through a character at a time...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to Robert's, but the "vectorized" version:

```
s1 <- unlist(strsplit(string1, ""))
s2 <- unlist(strsplit(string_reference, ""))
paste0(Filter(Negate(is.na), ifelse(s1 == s2 & s1 == ".", NA, s1)), collapse="")
# [1] "GCTCCCCTCCATGAAGTA...CTTCACATCCGTGTCCGGCCTGGCCGCGGAGAGCCC"
```

I quote "vectorized" because the vectorization is happening on the characters of your string vectors.  This assumes there is only one element in your string vectors.  If you had multiple elements in your string vectors you would have to loop through the results of `strsplit`.

Comment: Great! `paste0` is redundant since `collapse = ""`.

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski, true, although it's not because `collapse` is "", rather, it's because there is only one vector.

Answer (score 7):

I'd just use R's truly vectorised subsetting and logical comparison methods...

```
# Split the strings
x <- strsplit( c( string1 , string_reference ) , "" )
# Compare and remove dots from string1 when dots also appear in the reference string at the same position
paste( x[[1]][ ! (x[[2]]== "." & x[[1]] == ".") ] , collapse = "" )
#[1] "GCTCCCCTCCATGAAGTA...CTTCACATCCGTGTCCGGCCTGGCCGCGGAGAGCCC"
```

Comment: Simon, I think the user wants to remove the dots that appear in the same position (hence remove the one at 39, and the first set of dots as well).  That said, I wouldn't bet my life on it...

Comment: But +1 for the simpler use of subsetting.

Comment: @BrodieG of course! And actually, that is exactly what my code does, I just posted the result of an old expression up there not what my command actually did. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Using `intersect` to find the overlapping `.`'s

```
cutpos <- do.call(intersect, 
        sapply(list(string_reference,string1), gregexpr, pattern=".", fixed=TRUE)
          )
paste(strsplit(string1,"",fixed=TRUE)[[1]][-cutpos],collapse="")
#[1] "GCTCCCCTCCATGAAGTA...CTTCACATCCGTGTCCGGCCTGGCCGCGGAGAGCCC"
```

---

A small variation of the above (courtesy of @Arun):

```
attr(cutpos, 'match.length') <- rep(1L, length(cutpos))
attr(cutpos, 'useBytes') <- TRUE

do.call(paste0, c(regmatches(string1, list(cutpos), invert=TRUE), collapse=""))
## [1] "GCTCCCCTCCATGAAGTA...CTTCACATCCGTGTCCGGCCTGGCCGCGGAGAGCCC"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
string1v <- strsplit(string1, "")[[1]]
string_referencev <- strsplit(string_reference, "")[[1]]
stopifnot(length(string1v) == length(string_referencev))
finalstring <- paste(vapply(seq_along(string1v), function(ind) {
  if (string1v[ind] == '.' && string_referencev[ind] == '.') ''
  else string1v[ind] 
}, character(1)), collapse = "")
```